# How to Define a JPA Entity Over a Database Partitioned Table

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have a database partitioned table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [integration].[entity_key_map] (
    [entity_key_map_id] int /*varchar(64)*/NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [business_entity_alias] CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [business_key_1] VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    [business_key_2] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [business_key_3] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [business_key_4] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [business_key_5] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [system_alias] CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [system_entity_alias] CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    [system_key_1] VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    [system_key_2] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [system_key_3] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [system_key_4] VARCHAR(64) NULL,
    [system_key_5] VARCHAR(64) NULL
)
ON entity_key_map_ps ([system_entity_alias])
GO
ALTER TABLE [integration].[entity_key_map]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [ekm_pk]
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([entity_key_map_id], [system_entity_alias])
GO
```

The partition column, `system_entity_alias`, is required on the primary key, making it a compound PK. This leads to the use of a PK class defining `@Embeddable` and an entity class using `@EmbeddedId`.

My JPA entity is defined thus:

```
@EmbeddedId
private EntityKeyMapPK idClass;

@Column(name = "business_entity_alias", nullable = false, length = 5)
@JsonProperty("businessEntityAlias")
private EntityType businessEntityAlias;

@Column(name = "business_key_1", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty("businessKey1")
private String businessKey1;

@Column(name = "business_key_2")
@JsonProperty("businessKey2")
private String businessKey2;

@Column(name = "business_key_3")
@JsonProperty("businessKey3")
private String businessKey3;

@Column(name = "business_key_4")
@JsonProperty("businessKey4")
private String businessKey4;

@Column(name = "business_key_5")
@JsonProperty("businessKey5")
private String businessKey5;

@Column(name = "system_alias", nullable = false, length = 5)
@JsonProperty("systemAlias")
private SystemType systemAlias;

@Column(name = "system_key_1", nullable = false)
@JsonProperty("systemKey1")
private String systemKey1;

@Column(name = "system_key_2")
@JsonProperty("systemKey2")
private String systemKey2;

@Column(name = "system_key_3")
@JsonProperty("systemKey3")
private String systemKey3;

@Column(name = "system_key_4")
@JsonProperty("systemKey4")
private String systemKey4;

@Column(name = "system_key_5")
@JsonProperty("systemKey5")
private String systemKey5;
```

And EntityKeyMapPK looks like this:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "entity_key_map_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long entityKeyMapId;

@Column(name = "system_entity_alias", nullable = false)
private EntityType systemEntityAlias;
```

The problem is, that Hibernate *still* generates an insert statement using `entity_key_map_id`, passing it a null value, despite using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and `insertable = false, updatable = false`. The actual error is:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 544, SQLState: S0001
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'entity_key_map' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement]
```

Hibernate must generate an insert statement that does not reference `entity_key_map_id`, allowing the database to assign its internally generated ID. The following statements work as expected at the SQL CLI:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO [integration].[entity_key_map]
        ([business_entity_alias]
        ,[business_key_1]
        ,[system_alias]
        ,[system_entity_alias]
        ,[system_key_1]
        )
    VALUES
        ('CONT'
        ,'some.two@email.address'
        ,'MSTR'
        ,'PTY'
        ,'987654321'
        )
COMMIT
GO

SELECT * FROM [integration].[entity_key_map]
GO
```

How do I define the classes to obtain this behaviour?

Kindly note: Using JPA partitioning (multiple DB instances) is not an option--*unless I've missed something!*--and please simply accept the need for DB partitioning on this table.

Thanks.